# Parse LDAP DN string into key value pairs in ruby

Tags: ruby, ldap

I have a DN string like this as part of a query result:

```
uid=xyz.abc,ou=Users,o=abc,dc=org,dc=com
```

I cannot get them as separate parts via the query, because the string is returned a nested value for an attribute in the query. And the [LDAP library for Ruby](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-ldap/Net/LDAP/DN) does not seem to have a way of parsing a DN string or initializing an instance of `Net::LDAP::DN` from a string.

I could use `.split(',')` and `.split('=')` natively to parse the string into key value pairs but that would not handle escaping as described in the source code of [each_pair method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-ldap/Net/LDAP/DN#each_pair-instance_method).

Is there a way to leverage the escape logic in the `each_pair` method of Ruby LDAP library to parse the DN string? Or is there an easy alternative way to implement escape logic for DN?

Comment: Ruby has native parsing support for these - https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Name.html though I see the separator is different...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able do something like:

```
dn_string.each_pair.to_a.to_h
```

to get an array of hashes like:

```
[
  { 'uid' => 'xyz' },
  { 'dc' => 'org' },
  { 'dc' => 'com' }
]
```

Comment: This would work if `dn_string` is an instance of `Net::LDAP::DN`. But in this case I get the DN as a string.

Comment: Can you do something like `Net::LDAP::DN.new(dc)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution:

```rb
require 'net/ldap/dn'
dn = Net::LDAP::DN.new('uid=xyz.abc,ou=Users,o=abc,dc=org,dc=com')
dn.enum_for(:each_pair).map { |key, value| [key, value] }.to_h
```